# Calling dll from kernel mode c++ windows

Tags: dll, load, kernel, driver, call

How would I go about calling a dll from kernel mode?

I have tried making a custom lib file using multiple techniques but I cannot get anything to work. I have also researched on google but cannot seem to find anything. I was also curious if it was possible to create entries in the import address table from c++ or at link time?

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental issue for a DLL in kernel mode is whether the DLL calls any **user-mode code**. If a DLL contains anything other than **native kernel API calls**, you'll get linker errors if you try to link your driver with it when you build (and the kernel wouldn't load it anyway)

check the following link
[Calling a DLL in a Kernel-Mode Driver](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/Driver/tips/KmDLL.mspx)

Edit:

Another useful link

[DLLs in Kernel Mode  Tim Roberts](http://www.wd-3.com/archive/KernelDlls.htm)

Comment: The dll is BOOTVID.DLL which is part of windows. I cannot find any lib for it because it is only used internally.